# Delete a file with ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file

I'm trying to delete a file with ajax request:

javascript:

```
function deleteFile(file_path)
{
    var r = confirm("Sure?")
    if(r == true)
    {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'delete_file.php',
          data: {'file' : file_path },
          method: 'GET',
          success: function (response) {
             alert('Deleted!');

          },
          error: function () {
             alert('Not Deleted!');

          }
        });
    }
}
```

delete_file.php :

```
unlink($_GET['file']);
```

It returns true on succes,but the file is not deleted.

Comment: does your php/server instance have read/write/modify permissions in the folder where you are trying to delete?

Comment: Check your link path before unlink. May be you link was relative not absolute

Comment: You should probably go into Debug mode and check the content of the `response` variable - or just point your web browser at the path (`delete_file.php?file..`). Possbily PHP is giving you errors, such as permission denied, but still returning a `200 OK` status code.

Comment: I will check and return with a review

Comment: There's a HTTP verb called `DELETE`. If you <3 semantics, use that over `GET`.

Comment: I found the issue.The problem was at php,file_name was wrong..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the response in AJAX, Best is use JSON DATA to check the response:

```
// Default AJAX request type is GET so no need to define  
$.ajax({
      url: 'delete_file.php',
      data: {'file' : file_path },
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function (response) {
         if( response.status === true ) {
             alert('File Deleted!');
         }
         else alert('Something Went Wrong!');
      }
    });
```

Do It like this in PHP:

```
// First Check if file exists
$response = array('status'=>false);

if( file_exists('FILE_PATH/FILENAME') ) {
    unlink('FILE_PATH/FILENAME');
    $response['status'] = true;
}

// Send JSON Data to AJAX Request
echo json_encode($response);
```

Make sure you are giving the complete path with filename to [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function

Answer (score 1):

Try this you need to check file, give permission, then delete it

```
$filename = 'full absolute file path';
if(file_exists($filename)) {
    @chmod($filename, 0777);
    @unlink($filename);
    return true;
}
```

As there can be two issues either the file path is not correct or the file is not having permission.

With the above code both will be checked.